# How to use the 1st argument of the boost::asio::signal_set::async_wait's handler?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, boost-system

```cpp
void handler(boost::system::error_code const& e, int s)
{
  if (!e) { /* I see it */ }
  else { /* but I don't understand which situations the case occurs in. */ }
}
```

What errors can generally happen in an application for the case?
Thanks for your explaination.

Answer (score 1):

Error codes are like a "qualified enum": a tuple of (value, category) where category distinguishes different error domains.

You *can* use `code()` and `category()` to query those raw values, but that is rarely what you want. In fact it's an anti-pattern, as it's very common to lose the category information in the process or even misinterpret (by assuming the category to be the one you commonly expect).

Instead use the higher level accessor: `message()` (which gets a string description for the error_code using its actual category instance). This is perfect for logging - many libraries will even return localized strings.

Recent versions of boost add optional `source_location()` and a `to_string()` method.

### Checking Error Conditions

As a rule you should never compare `error_codes`. Instead, use `error_condition`. The standard describes these:

- error_code holds a platform-dependent error code
- error_condition holds a portable error code

Though simplified, that's a good starting point.

Conditions allow one to handle conditions that may manifest with different *error codes* depending on platform, implementation and/or configuration.

An exception [sic] is when you write to a specific platform or implementation where you know a specific error_code is always expected.

E.g. in Asio you could have:

```
 asio::io_context io;
 asio::stead_timer timer(io, 3s);
 timer.async_wait([](error_code ec) {
      bool canceled = ec == asio::error::operation_aborted;
      std::cerr << (canceled?"canceled":"timed out") << "\n";
 });
```

This checks a specific `error_code` instance.

> ***Note*** that even though `error::operation_aborted` is an enum value, the comparison takes the category into account because the conversion constructor invokes the `make_error_code` customization point which automatically adds the correct category.
>
> The analogous implicit "factory" `make_error_condition` applies to error condition enums (typically called `XXXXX_errc`)

However, on other occasions you would prefer to check an error condition.

The best current write-up I know about error codes and conditions is by Peter Dimov in the Boost System Introduction: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/system/doc/html/system.html#usage_testing_for_specific_error_conditions

- A seminal articles series from 2010 by Chris Kohlhoff himself: http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/system-error-support-in-c0x-part-1.html in case you want to learn more about the inner workings
- In between: Andzrej's blog series https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/tag/error_code/